# Nested async comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, dictionary-comprehension

The following works fine:

```
async def foo(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return n

async def bar():
    return {
        n: await foo(n) for n in [1, 2, 3]
    }
```

But the nested version fails with `SyntaxError: asynchronous comprehension outside of an asynchronous function`:

```
async def bar():
    return {
        i: {
            n: await foo(n) for n in [1, 2, 3]
        } for i in [1,2,3]
    }
```

Comment: It looks like a bug, so I [reported it](https://bugs.python.org/issue41159) as one.